# How to combine a ViewModel and static objects

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, viewmodel

I am new to WPF but I did C# for quite some time now. Maybe a similar question like mine was already answered somewhere, but I really would not know what search term to use for this.

So on my Window I use a graph from OxyPlot library. Its ItemsSource is bound to a `ObservableCollection<DataPoint>` in the ViewModel.

What can I do if I want this DataPoint list to be available in the whole application?

Does it make sense in this case to create a class like this:

```
public class Global
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> DataPoints { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>();
}
```

And point to it in the ViewModel:

```
using static MyProject.Global;
public class MainViewModel
{
public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> MyPoints { get => DataPoints; }
}
```

Or is it better to not put this list into the ViewModel and bind directly to Global.DataPoints?

Is it anyways a good approach to create a project-wide static class or is sharing objects over the application done in a different way?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: This is a legitimate question, I don't know why people on SO eat their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that MVVM is only a system to separate data representation from business logic from a visual presentation. How the data is accessed by other components is not necessarily relevant.

I would put the collection on the VM. Then instantiate the VM in the app class and assign it to a static member property on that class. Then you can have other sections of code access the property on the VM via the app class's static.

---

As an aside one doesn't need an `ObservableCollection` to make binding work. One can use a generic List and bind to it (with `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the VM). One only needs the `ObservableCollection` when items are dynamically going to be added or removed from the collection and one wants what it is bound to, to handle that specific event.

I have such an example on my blog:

[Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)